# Time out on querying large elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest, sense

I queried a large index using a very large size, as I want to retrieve every matching document in a large index, but I got a timeout after a long time. No result is returned. Is there any other way to get all data without timing out?
My query:

```
{
"size": 90000000,
"query": { 
    "filtered": {"query": {"match_all":{}},"filter":{"term": {"isbn": 475869}}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) if you need to retrieve a large amount of data.

First, initiate the scroll with your query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?scroll=1m' -d '{
    "size": 5000,
    "query": {
        "term" : {
            "isbn" : "475869"
        }
    }
}'
```

Then you'll get the first 5000 documents as well as a `_scroll_id` token in the response, which you can use to perform the subsequent requests.

Then you can repeatedly perform the next requests using the `scroll_id` token from the previous response in order to get the next batch of 5000 documents, until you get no results anymore.

```
curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll' -d '{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1" 
}'
```

Since you're using Jest, there's a [`SearchScroll`](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/162ebbec583820aa96479ffe6d98c015da1595d6/jest-common/src/main/java/io/searchbox/core/SearchScroll.java) class you can use. See in [test cases](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/162ebbec583820aa96479ffe6d98c015da1595d6/jest-common/src/test/java/io/searchbox/core/SearchScrollTest.java) how that class is used.

Comment: @DevEx have you been able to try this out?